# how to add divider to NavigationRail in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to add a divider between each `NavigationRailDestination`.
inside  `NavigationRail` there is destinations where we add `NavigationRailDestination`.

it's only accept children from the type `NavigationRailDestination`.

I tried to do it in this way but it's not what I wanted, there are unnecessary padding I can't get ride of it and it's do actions when I click on it

Here is my code:

```
 NavigationRail(
  backgroundColor: customTheme.card,
  leading: IconButton(
      onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      icon: Icon(
        FeatherIcons.chevronLeft,
        size: 20,
        color: theme.colorScheme.onBackground,
      )),
  selectedIndex: _selectedIndex,
  onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
      controller.animateToPage(index,
          duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 250),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut);
    });
  },
  labelType: NavigationRailLabelType.selected,
  /*------------- Build Tabs -------------------*/
  destinations: [
    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.dashboard),
      selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.dashboard),
      label: FxText.titleSmall('Dashboard',
          fontWeight: 500, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
    ),
    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: Divider(color: Colors.black),
      selectedIcon: Divider(color: Colors.black),
      label: FxText.titleSmall('',
          fontWeight: 100, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
      padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:1,left: 10,right:10,bottom: 1)
    ),

    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.tour),
      selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.tour),
      label: FxText.titleSmall('Tours',
          fontWeight: 600, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
    ),
    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.flight),
      selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.flight),
      label: FxText.titleSmall('Flights',
          fontWeight: 600, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
    ),


    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.hotel),
      selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.hotel),
      label: FxText.titleSmall('Hotels',
          fontWeight: 600, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
    ),

    NavigationRailDestination(
        icon: Divider(color: Colors.black),
        selectedIcon: Divider(color: Colors.black),
        label: FxText.titleSmall('',
            fontWeight: 100, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
        padding:EdgeInsets.only(top:1,left: 10,right:10,bottom: 1)
    ),
    NavigationRailDestination(
      icon: const Icon(Icons.payment),
      selectedIcon: const Icon(Icons.payment),
      label: FxText.titleSmall('Payments',
          fontWeight: 600, color: theme.colorScheme.primary),
    ),
  ],
),
```

This the result I want to get but without that space between icons and the dividers:

[image: Expected result]